# Ошибка при импортировании библиотеки Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Всем добрый день. Делаю телеграм бота на Python. Возникла проблема при импортировании библиотеки telebot. Приложил скриншот. Использую новейший питон, модуль **pip install pytelegrambotapi установил**. Подскажите пожалуйста как решить проблему. Заранее спасибо[image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02ZLd.jpg)

Comment: Неужели сфотографировать экран на телефон и прикрепить сюда оказалось легче, чем скопировать текст? Не суть, просто придираюсь. А проблему воспроизвести не получается. Какая версия питона? Какая версия пакета? https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/telebot/__init__.py#L463 в исходниках в этом файле на строке 463 в помине нет def async... откуда он взялся?

Comment: async - это ключевое слово, которым нельзя функции называть... природа ошибки понятна. Но как ваше окружение пришло в такое состояние? Разработчики telebot не стали бы релизить такой код.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Питон вериси 3.8.2, пишу в пайчарме. В коде использую вот: @bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"]) и @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True). Но из-за этого не может быть ошибка. Как исправить это, почему цепляется к import telebot?

Comment: Выполните `pip show pytelegrambotapi`, сейчас актуальная версия 3.6.7, какая у вас? В старых версиях питона async не было зарезервированным словом и так функции можно было называть. Но теперь нет, автор в свое время назвал так один свой декоратор, но уже давно исправил это https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/commit/c8b2b1415745abc5278749dfc42e059bd65f332b Так что переустановка/обновление должно помочь. А еще рекомендую использовать `virtualenv`.