# Телеграмм бот на Python , в cmd выдает ошибку def async(): ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, telegram-bot, cmd, telebot

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_echo(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, message.text)
bot.polling (none_stop = True)
```

ОШИБКА В CMD :

> C:\Users\79117\learn python>python sef.py Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File "C:\Users\79117\learn python\sef.py", line 1, in
>
> import telebot   File "C:\Users\79117\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot_*init*_.py",
> line 463
> def async():
> ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (ссылка `править` под вопросом)

Comment: Почти дубликат, задан о том же, но в совсем никуда не годном виде https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1110896/Ошибка-при-импортировании-библиотеки-python почитайте комменты к вопросу

Comment: Выполните `from telebot import version` `print(version.__version__)` и напишите результат. Возможно, у вас слишком старая версия библиотеки. У меня этот код выдал версию `3.7.3` и там нет такой проблемы. Кст, насчет скриншотов, это совет, но так повышается шанс получить отклик -- людям не нравятся ошибки и код в виде картинок, могут поставить минус и проигнорировать вопрос :) Если не знаете как копировать из cmd текст, то это просто: выделяете мышкой и тыкаете правой кнопкой, это скопирует в буфер обмена